# Http request not reaching MVC Backend. No Errors Showing Why

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, model-view-controller

I am trying to recreate the Tour of Heroes tutorial program in Angular, but this time with a MVC backend. however, there seems to be a disconnect between my HTTP Get Request, and the server when I try to get the list of Heroes. I'm not sure what could be causing this issue, as there isn't any error output showing when I wrong the applications. (both the frontend and backend are running from VSC and VS respectively). Any input you guys can provide would be fantastic.

Below is the code for my heroes service, and heroes controller.

```````````````
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

     import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'; 
     import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

     import { Hero } from './heroes';
     import { MessageService } from './messages.service';

     const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
      };

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:44339/api/values';  // URL to web api

  constructor( private http: HttpClient, private messageService:    MessageService) { }

  /** GET heroes from the server */
  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl);

  }

}
``````````````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HeroApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace HeroApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HeroesController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Hero> GetAll()
        {
            var list = new List<Hero>();
            list.Add(new Hero() { name = "Dynamo" , id = 1});
            list.Add(new Hero() { name = "Captain Fission", id = 2 });
            return list;
        }


        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Hero Get(int Id)
        {
            return new Hero(){ id = Id };
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }


        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }


        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
``````````````
```````````````

Comment: The browser console can display all client-side XHRs. Do you see any request there at all?

Comment: the following warnings are the only output that come from the console                            **client:148 [WDS] Warnings while compiling.
warnings @ client:148
 ./node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.js 167:24-52
"export '__platform_browser_private__' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'**@client 154

Comment: If you're getting warnings, please add them to your question. (also, you might need to turn on XHRs in the console's filter settings)

Comment: Could you please  try to update the api URL to private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:44339/api/Heroes/GetAll';

Comment: Sorry, I meant switch it to 'heroes' over 'values' before I had posted it, but I forgot to fix my initial post to include that. the inclusion of GetAll at the end of the url doesn't seem to work. same results

Comment: the wrong URL, I think, you put controller name as values it should be Heroes

Comment: So did some edits and now I have an error that I'm familiar with, but still not sure how to resolve it ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44339/api/heroes/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.``` I know the urls need to match, but I'm not sure how to go about correcting that in code so that they DO match.

Answer (score 0):

Are you subscribing to the Observable returned from getHeroes?

```
heroService.getHeros()
```

Will not fire a http request, it will return an observable that fires a http request when subscribed to.

```
heroService.getHeros().subscriber(heros => {
  // do stuff with heroes, this will fire off a http request
});
```